# What was the Sin of Gomorrah?

Tags: history, sin, genesis, sodom

We all know the sin of Sodom. But my question is, why was Gomorrah destroyed? Please give references to your answer.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodom_and_Gomorrah) has much to say on this, from Jewish and Islamic viewpoints as well as Christian. And [Jude 1:7](http://www.biblegateway.com/bible?passage=Jude%201%3A7;&version=NIV;) is relevant.

Answer (score 12):

God destroyed Sodom and Gomorrah because of their grievous sins along with other towns in the plain of the Jordan, except Zoar.

> *Genesis 18:20-21 (NIV)* Then the Lord said, “The outcry against **Sodom and Gomorrah** is so great and their sin so grievous that I will go down
>   and see if what they have done is as bad as the outcry that has
>   reached me. If not, I will know.”

There were five cities in the plain of the Jordan - Sodom, Gomorrah, Admah, Zeboyim and Zoar.

> *Genesis 14:8 (NIV)* Then the king of **Sodom**, the king of **Gomorrah**, the king of **Admah**, the king of **Zeboyim** and the king of Bela (that is, **Zoar**) marched out and drew up their battle
>   lines in the Valley of Siddim.

After Lot and Abram were separated, Lot chose to live in the plain of Jordan.

> *Genesis 13:11-13 (NIV)* So Lot chose for himself the whole plain of the
>   Jordan and set out toward the east. The two men parted company: Abram
>   lived in the land of Canaan, while Lot lived among the cities of the
>   plain and **pitched his tents near Sodom**. Now the people of Sodom were
>   wicked and were sinning greatly against the Lord.

The four cities - Sodom, Gomorrah, Admah, Zeboyim were destroyed but Zoar was spared because Lot pleaded the two angels to spare the town of Zoar as he wanted to run there for safety.

> *Genesis 19:23-24 (NIV)* By the time Lot reached Zoar, the sun had risen
>   over the land. Then the Lord rained down burning sulfur on Sodom and
>   Gomorrah—from the Lord out of the heavens.
>
> *Genesis 19:29 (NIV)* So when **God destroyed the cities of the plain**, he
>   remembered Abraham, and he brought Lot out of the catastrophe that
>   overthrew the cities where Lot had lived.

The city of Sodom was known for [sodomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodomy) and that is exactly how we get this English word. The sins of Sodom and Gomorrah as recorded by prophet Ezekiel, ~1500 years later -

> *Ezekiel 16:49-50 (NIV)* “‘Now this was the sin of your sister Sodom: She and her daughters were **arrogant**, overfed and **unconcerned**; they did
>   **not help the poor and needy**. They were **haughty** and did **detestable**
>   things before me. Therefore I did away with them as you have seen.

The sins of Sodom and Gomorrah as recorded by apostle Jude in the New Testament, ~2000 years later -

> *Jude 1:7 (NIV)* In a similar way, Sodom and Gomorrah and the surrounding towns gave themselves up to **sexual immorality and
>   perversion**. They serve as an example of those who suffer the
>   punishment of eternal fire.